# HTML - Table with non relational height.

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make each row/column in a table have it's own Unique height, that way if I wanted a table that looks like this, I could:

```
+-----------------------------+
|  Data  |   Data    |  Data  |
|  Data  +-----------+  Data  |
|  Data  |   Data    |  Data  |
+--------+-----------+--------+
```

Sorry if this is not descriptive enough, as I don't know any other way to explain it. The goal is for this to be a single `<table>` that doesn't have the entire row's height effected by a single column. Each columns height is independent of the row.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this layout by using the `rowspan` attribute

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Data<br>Data<br>Data</td>  
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td rowspan="2">Data<br>Data<br>Data</td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [rowspan](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) attribute of the `<td>` element:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Data<br>
                        Data<br>
                        Data</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Data</td>
       <td>Data</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td rowspan="2">Data<br>
                       Data<br>
                       Data</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a **[sample JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsve/tg5mwm53/)**.